# Display fields from temp table in select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL. The problem is that it only displays results in the output for the the following : wp.gtid, wp.first_name etc I want to display the results from wpe.gtid, wpe.first_name etc too. So that i can see easily a comparison of the fields side by side.

```
with dups as (
    select 
          wp.GtId
        from CORE.WeccoParty wp
    where exists (select 1
                  from CORE.WeccoParty wpe
                -- where wp.Tin = wpe.Tin
                where wp.FirstName = wpe.LastName
                  and   wp.GtId     <> wpe.GtId    
              )
      )
       select distinct
      wp.GtId, 
      wp.CrmPartyId, 
      wp.LegalName, 
      wp.BusinessClass, 
      wp.RmFullName, 
      wp.PbeFullName, 
      wp.OverallClientStatus, 
     wp.OverallRpStatus, 
       wp.FirstName,
      wp.LastName,
      wp.Tin


from CORE.WeccoParty wp
join dups d on d.GtId = wp.GtId
order by 1,2
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but check out `FULL OUTER JOIN` rather than a standard `INNER JOIN` like you're using.

Comment: Thanks for that. So for example from above the select distinct is only selecting wp.fieldname. I want it to display wp.field name and wpe.fieldname as i have aliased them above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K1205, when I checked your code it seems to identify [duplicate entries](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/delete-duplicate-rows-using-row-number-partition-by-order-by.aspx) having the same FirstName but different GtId values

So maybe you can use Row_Number() function with partition by clause

Could you please check following SQL?

```
select 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition By wp.FirstName Order By wp.GtId) as rn,
    wp.GtId, 
    wp.CrmPartyId, 
    wp.LegalName, 
    wp.BusinessClass, 
    wp.RmFullName, 
    wp.PbeFullName, 
    wp.OverallClientStatus, 
    wp.OverallRpStatus, 
    wp.FirstName,
    wp.LastName,
    wp.Tin
from CORE.WeccoParty wp
order by wp.FirstName, rn
```

I hope following CTE query helps you for solution
The data (firstname and gtid) from duplicates are added as new columns after the first entry for the same firstname

```
with rawdata as (
    select 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition By wp.FirstName Order By wp.GtId) as rn,
        wp.GtId, 
        wp.CrmPartyId, 
        wp.LegalName, 
        wp.BusinessClass, 
        wp.RmFullName, 
        wp.PbeFullName, 
        wp.OverallClientStatus, 
        wp.OverallRpStatus, 
        wp.FirstName,
        wp.LastName,
        wp.Tin
    from WeccoParty wp
)
select t1.*, t2.GtId, t2.FirstName 
from rawdata as t1
inner join rawdata as t2
    on t1.FirstName = t2.FirstName and
       t1.rn <> t2.rn
where t1.rn = 1
order by t1.FirstName, t2.rn
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the help. At present with my sql it displays : wp.GtId, 
      wp.CrmPartyId, 
      wp.LegalName, 
      wp.BusinessClass, 
      wp.RmFullName, 
      wp.PbeFullName, 
      wp.OverallClientStatus, 
     wp.OverallRpStatus, 
       wp.FirstName,
      wp.LastName,
      wp.Tin. I also want to show wpe.FirstName, wpe.LastName, wpe.TIN

Comment: Hi K1205, I modified my answer and added a second query showing how you can display original and duplicate rows data side by side